# Fill items in combobox bounded to collectionviewsource

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I have a edit customers window. All fields which were entered by the user are displayed in this window. I also have a Gender field, which is a combobox. The items of this combobox must be populated from table t_Geslacht. The ID of the table t_Geslacht and the gender column are joined. In this window the user can navigate through records using collectionview. When I bind the combobox to the gender table, I get the values. But the value doesn't change when the user navigates through the records.

Here is my XAML of the combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="geslachtComboBox1" Grid.Column="1" DisplayMemberPath="Geslacht"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource lut_GeslachtViewSource}}" 
          SelectedValuePath="GeslachtID" Margin="10.2,5,0,5" Grid.Row="0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120">
   <ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
</ComboBox>
```

Here is the code for the collection:

```
customersViewSource = ((System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)(this.FindResource("t_KlantenViewSource")));
System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<AOV.t_Klanten> customersQuery = this.Getlt_KlantenQuery(aoventities);
customersViewSource.Source = customersQuery.Execute(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption.AppendOnly);
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sorry, if I didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind combo box `SelectedValue` property to the "GenderID" property of Customer.

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="geslachtComboBox1" Grid.Column="1" 
           DisplayMemberPath="Geslacht"     
           ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource lut_GeslachtViewSource}}" SelectedValuePath="GeslachtID"
           SelectedValue="{Binding GenderID}"... //change to the property name for Gender in customer object..
```